# Android EditText money input Regex without "$" symbol

Tags: java, regex

I want to enter decimal numbers like "23.50", "250.75". The following code provide this but it put front of numbers a "$" symbol like "$23.50", "$250.75" .. I want to remove dollar symbol and tried a few way but i couldn't. How can i change regex and displaying?

the following codde :

```
    inputAmount.setRawInputType(Configuration.KEYBOARD_12KEY);


    inputAmount.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if(!s.toString().matches("^\\$(\\d{1,3}(\\,\\d{3})*|(\\d+))(\\.\\d{2})?"))
            {
                String userInput= ""+s.toString().replaceAll("[^\\d]", "");
                StringBuilder cashAmountBuilder = new StringBuilder(userInput);

                while (cashAmountBuilder.length() > 3 && cashAmountBuilder.charAt(0) == '0') {
                    cashAmountBuilder.deleteCharAt(0);
                }
                while (cashAmountBuilder.length() < 3) {
                    cashAmountBuilder.insert(0, '0');
                }
                cashAmountBuilder.insert(cashAmountBuilder.length()-2, '.');
                cashAmountBuilder.insert(0,'$');

                inputAmount.setText(cashAmountBuilder.toString());
                // keeps the cursor always to the right
                Selection.setSelection(inputAmount.getText(), cashAmountBuilder.toString().length());

            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: Don't copy a piece of code that you don't understand.

Comment: very helpful knowledge thank you @devnull. you  help to me very well

Answer (score 5):

```
  @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            if(!s.toString().matches("^\\ (\\d{1,3}(\\,\\d{3})*|(\\d+))(\\.\\d{2})?$"))
            {
                String userInput= ""+s.toString().replaceAll("[^\\d]", "");
                StringBuilder cashAmountBuilder = new StringBuilder(userInput);

                while (cashAmountBuilder.length() > 3 && cashAmountBuilder.charAt(0) == '0') {
                    cashAmountBuilder.deleteCharAt(0);
                }
                while (cashAmountBuilder.length() < 3) {
                    cashAmountBuilder.insert(0, '0');
                }
                cashAmountBuilder.insert(cashAmountBuilder.length()-2, '.');
                cashAmountBuilder.insert(0, ' ');

                edAmountAddMoney.setText(cashAmountBuilder.toString());
                // keeps the cursor always to the right
                Selection.setSelection(edAmountAddMoney.getText(), cashAmountBuilder.toString().length());

            }
        }
```

i use space instead of $ and it work for me

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line:

```
cashAmountBuilder.insert(0,'$');
```

And remove the `\\$` from your regular expression.

Comment: i removed already, but when i enter a digit after remove, application give error